# I tried to retrieve keyvault secret by appservice using MSI in my local machine but got the error:java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused:connect

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-appservice

This current code is giving me the error `error:java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused:connect`

```
AppServiceMSICredentials msiCredentials = new AppServiceMSICredentials(AzureEnvironment.AZURE,msiEndpoint, msiSecret);
keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(msiCredentials);
SecretBundle secretBundle = keyVaultClient.getSecret(keyvault url, secretName);
```

Comment: `MSI_ENDPOINT` and `MSI_SECRET` change every time you restart the App Service. Please check if they are correct.

Comment: i have cross checked in azure portal MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET value is same as that is mapped in the code

Comment: Your code is correct. Please try to 1) set the **status** as `on` under Identity of App service, 2)add an Access Policy in azure key vault, 3)turn off MSI for the Function, then re-enable it.

Comment: crosschecked the above points and it seems fine . Is it something like we can check or validate it only after deploying to App service or can it be checked even in our local machine since I am facing this connection refused error

Comment: Does it report this error only when running locally, but work well in App service?

Comment: Not yet deployed in AppService , while trying to validate in local I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I test the [sample](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Azure_AppService_ManagedIdentity) in my local, and face the same error. But I can't find detailed information if `AppServiceMSICredentials` supports access key vault locally.

You could try the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/tutorial-managed-identities-key-vault) using a managed identity to connect Key Vault to an Azure Spring Cloud app.

The tutorial is based on **Azure Identity** library, and you could learn more about it with Java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth.

```
private void getSecretWithManagedIdentity() {
    ManagedIdentityCredential managedIdentityCredential = new ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder()
            .maxRetry(1)
            .retryTimeout(duration -> Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .build();

    secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
            .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
            .credential(managedIdentityCredential)
            .buildClient();

    KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret(secret-name);
}
```